# How to integrate Safe with Telegram?

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core, web3auth

I want to create a safe wallet for users based on telegram inside a bot.

Could you guide me what components and in what order are required?

I am still struggling to understand how telegram could act as signer in the wallet and which apis are needed.

For help grateful, best

Tobias

Answer (score 0):

Telegram won't be able to act as a signer, as for now the [safeAuth](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/auth-kit) only supports Google Auth.

You would need to build a specific integration to handle identity (for instance ask users for their email so that safeAuth can create an EOA for them) and then interact with Safes with our SDK.

Hope it helps,
Louis